# SQL Server : multiple select statements on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to count many different values in one column in one table, all in one query.

**EDIT:** Query now works with suggestions by @Red Edit to move the aliases outside of each select and by @dnoeth to move the 'from' line- thanks!  I have one more question, which I will add a comment for.

```
    select 
        m1.mods_in_study,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.study as m2 
         where m2.mods_in_study like '%CT%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as CT,
        (select count(*)
         from dbo.study as m3 
         where m3.mods_in_study like '%MR%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as MR,
        (select count(*)
         from dbo.study as m4 
         where m4.mods_in_study like '%CR%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as CR,
        (select count(*)
         from dbo.study as m5 
         where m5.mods_in_study like '%DX%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as DX,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.study as m6 
         where m6.mods_in_study like '%US%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as US,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.study as m7 
         where m7.mods_in_study like '%PT%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as PT,
        (select count(*)
         from dbo.study as m8 
         where m8.mods_in_study like '%NM%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as NM,
        (select count(*) 
         from dbo.study as m9
         where m9.mods_in_study like '%MG%'
           and study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
           and study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as MG
from dbo.study as m1
group by m1.mods_in_study
```

Right now, SQL is complaining about the '(' on the 2nd count.  Should I be using aliases for this query?  I know that a 'union' world work, but won't display correctly in my report as I need a column name for each count.

What am I doing wrong, or is there just a better way of going about this?

Here is what I am expecting the results to be:

```
CT  MR  CR  DX  US  PT  NM MG
130 39  240 12  45   7  17 121
```

Comment: Maybe you should clearly specify what you expect as result :-)

Comment: I'm trying to count each instance of 'CT', 'MR', 'CR', 'US' (and rest of them) separately, and they all exist in the 'mods_in_study' column.  I would like each count to have a header.

Comment: So your result should be a single row? Or one row for each existing value in `mods_in_study`?

Comment: that is my other question.  Right now, I've edited the code and it works, but it comes back with several rows, and I'm expecting a single row, with several counts.  I'll add an example to my question.

Comment: I edited my answer, this should fix it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the expected result set it's easier to understand :-)

To get a single row you don't need the `FROM`or `GROUP BY`, so simply remove the `m1.mods_in_study,`and the `from dbo.study as m1
group by m1.mods_in_study`

But as you always use the same conditions on the same table this can be simplified to

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN mods_in_study LIKE '%CT%' THEN 1 END) AS CT, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN mods_in_study LIKE '%MR%' THEN 1 END) AS MR, 
    ...
FROM dbo.study
WHERE study_datetime >= DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
  AND study_datetime < DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

MarkD's solution is quite similar...

Comment: thanks, this does now what I was expecting.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Not having a terminal at hand where I can test MSSQL but reading through the query it would seem like you are just missing a comma.

Comment: If I add a comma after each select statement, that new comma gets flagged as well by MSSQL

Comment: can you pass me your create statements for the tables you are using? Just to make sure I'm using the same setup as you are and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, you do need a comma after the closing `)` for each SELECT. What problem do you see if you do this? "Flagged by MSSQL" does not tell us the problem.

Comment: It's not only the missing comma. Right now all those SELECTs are Derived Tables and they need an alias.

Comment: No, they are only single columns so it will work without an alias. They will have column headings `(No column name)`. However, since the OP does want to refer to them by column name, the existing aliases need to move outside the ending `)` for the select: `(select count(*) ...) as CT, (select count(*) ...) as MR,` etc.

Comment: @Reg Edit: Those SELECT are not columns (=Scalar Subqueries) because they are added **after** the FROM, so they are *Derived Tables* which must have an alias.

Comment: @dnoeth, I don't see any FROM before them.

Comment: @dnoeth, I now see the question was edited. Yes, you're right--the OP only wanted single cols, but it wasn't going to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are after, I'd advise to code against the following pattern.
It is typically more efficient that the correlated sub-queries and a better practice;

```
SELECT   mods_in_study
        ,CT =   SUM (   CASE 
                            WHEN mods_in_study LIKE '%CT%' 
                            AND  study_datetime >= DATEADD(DAY ,DATEDIFF(DAY ,1 ,GETDATE()) ,0) 
                            AND  study_datetime < DATEADD(DAY ,DATEDIFF(DAY ,0 ,GETDATE()) ,0)
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                    )
        ,MR =   SUM (   CASE 
                            WHEN mods_in_study LIKE '%MR%' 
                            AND  study_datetime >= DATEADD(DAY ,DATEDIFF(DAY ,1 ,GETDATE()) ,0) 
                            AND  study_datetime < DATEADD(DAY ,DATEDIFF(DAY ,0 ,GETDATE()) ,0)
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                    )
        --  Etc...
FROM   dbo.study
GROUP BY mods_in_study
```

Comment: I'd appreciate the down-voter articulating their down-vote. Will happily remove my proposal if it is sensible.

Comment: This query worked, but it just wasn't what I was expecting for results.  I should have added what I was expecting as a result, but I wasn't exactly sure how it would look until I got some results back to tweak it.

Comment: There is no way for anyone to arrive at your posted result-set without us having the data. Please reverse your down-vote and improve your question. My post deals specifically with removing the subqueries you have in your code.

Comment: I did not down vote anyone's answer here, sorry that my question wasn't clear enough.  I have edited it though.  :(